# Nested Integral of exponential function with trigonometric identities

Tags: integration, special-functions, normal-distribution

Is there any possibility to simplify the following integral or any function that is equivalent to the following integral?

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{(\sigma_{o_x}^2+\sigma_{p_x}^2)(\sigma_{o_y}^2+\sigma_{p_y}^2)}} \int_0^d \int_0^{2\pi} \exp-\bigg[\frac{(r\cos\theta-\alpha_x)^2}{2(\sigma_{o_x}^2+\sigma_{p_x}^2)} + \frac{(r\sin\theta-\alpha_y)^2}{2(\sigma_{o_y}^2+\sigma_{p_y}^2)}  \bigg ]     r \; d\theta \;dr $$

Comment: I doubt it. You're effecitvely integrating a two-dimensional isotropic normal distribution over an ellipse.

Comment: I am integrating a 2-dimensional non-isotropic normal function over a circular region.

Comment: I know; that's the same thing (through a change of variables).